# preg_replace_callback não funciona

Tags: php, regex

Estou tentando trocar uma variáveis com preg_replace_callback, mas não estou tendo sucesso, alguém sabe onde está o erro??

```
 $replacements = array(
                '[PEDIDO]' => $oID,
                '[NOME]' => $order->customer['name'],
                '[VALOR]' => $order->totals['ot_subtotal'],
                '[FRETE]' => $order->totals['ot_shipping'],
                '[DESCONTO]' => $order->totals['ot_payment'],
                '[TOTAL]' => $order->totals['ot_total'],
            );

 $msg = preg_replace_callback('/[\w+]/', 
                        create_function('$matches',
                          'return $replacements[$matches[0]];'
                    , $m['msg']));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom que resolveu, mas eu preciso considerar alguns pontos e até mesmo explicar o porquê de seu código não ter funcionado como você esperava.

[create_function()](http://www.php.net/create_function) não só é um recurso perigoso por estar sujeita a todas as questões de segurança relacionadas com <strike>evil</strike> [eval()](http://www.php.net/eval), como também é ruim de performance.

Isso sem contar que as Closures foram introduzidas como alternativa no PHP 5.3 lançado em Junho de 2009 (mais de 5 anos atrás). Sugiro fortemente um upgrade.

Também, sempre que possível, considere **não** usar ERs. Se você não tem nenhum padrão regular, como você mesmo solucinou, trabalhar diretamente com as strings é muito mais fácil (e rápido).

Mas o motivo de não ter funcionado, **além** de dois erros de sintaxe, já que [create_function()](http://www.php.net/create_function) espera dois e não três argumentos e [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) espera três e não dois, **E** da falta de escapamento dos colchetes como apontado pelo @Jader, você sofreu do velho caso de [Escopo de Variáveis](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php).

Apesar de [create_function](http://www.php.net/create_function) retornar uma string, para [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) ela é um [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). Não que [create_function](http://www.php.net/create_function) retorne uma função, mas ela é interpretada como uma e, por isso, está sujeita às "restrições" de escopo local e global.

Em resumo:

```
$order = "Pedido: [PEDIDO]\nNome: [NOME]\nValor: [VALOR]\nFrete: [FRETE]\n Desconto: [DESCONTO]\nTotal: [TOTAL]";

$replacements = array(
                '[PEDIDO]' => 123,
                '[NOME]' => 'Bruno Augusto',
                '[VALOR]' => 69.00,
                '[FRETE]' => 0,
                '[DESCONTO]' => 69.00,
                '[TOTAL]' => 'It\'s FREE!',
            );

  $order = preg_replace_callback(

          '/\[\w+\]/', // Colchetes escapados

          create_function(

               // Variável globalizada

              '$matches', 'global $replacements; return $replacements[$matches[0]];'
          ),

          // Número de argumentos corrigido

          $order
);
```

Retornaria, como esperado:

> Pedido: 123 Nome: Bruno Augusto Valor: 69 Frete: 0 Desconto: 69 Total: It's FREE!

Answer (score 1):

Assim funcionou bem aqui:

```
$replacements = array(
                '[PEDIDO]' => $oID,
                '[NOME]' => $order->customer['name'],
                '[VALOR]' => $order->totals['ot_subtotal'],
                '[FRETE]' => $order->totals['ot_shipping'],
                '[DESCONTO]' => $order->totals['ot_payment'],
                '[TOTAL]' => $order->totals['ot_total'],
            );

   $msg = preg_replace_callback('/\[\w+\]/', 
                        function ($matches) {
                            global $replacements;
                            return $replacements[$matches[0]];
                        }
                    , $m['msg']);
```

Comment: aqui não, e eu tenho que usar create_function por causa da versão do php

Comment: Estou no celular agora... Coloca o global antes do return e verifica o fechamento da create_function, você esta fechando lá no final e deve fechar antes da vírgula.

Comment: Resolvi trocar a função do que ficar quebrando a cabeça, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu resolver. Mas eu esqueci de dizer que a sua regex também estava errada, faltou escapar os [  ]...

Comment: Se vai usar Closures não use `global`. Prefira o `use()` ;)

Answer (score 0):

A solução pra mim foi modificar a forma como eu estava fazendo para não perder mais tempo.

```
$in = array('[PEDIDO]','[NOME]','[VALOR]','[FRETE]','[DESCONTO]','[TOTAL]');
$out = array($oID, $order->customer['name'],$order->totals['ot_subtotal'],$order->totals['ot_shipping'],$order->totals['ot_payment'],$order->totals['ot_total']);  

$msg = str_replace($in, $out, $m['msg']);
```

Está ai se servir para alguém.